# sending var in html from view backbone

Tags: html, backbone.js

Hi I am learning backbone.js and as a part of a project I want to send  a variable from my view.js file in Backbone to the associated template(.html). How should i do it?

Currently I try to do the following but fail:
In View.js:

```
$( ".result" ).html( displayChoice );
```

In html template:

```
<% if(!displayChoice.localeCompare("true")) { %>
    <div class="name" id="choices"><%- choices[i].choice %></div>
<% } %>
```

Please tell me what is wrong in this approach.

Comment: You need to compile your template, also it is kind of unclear what you mean by 'send a variable to the associated template'

Comment: Compile the template using `var t = _.template(template_text)` and then convert it to HTML with `t({ displayChoice: displayChoice })`. This should have been covered by whatever tutorial you're using and it is covered in the [`_.template` docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template).